# How do l only render part of my component?

Tags: react-native

l have a list with data and a dropdown list with categories, when l open dropdown list l want to stop the list with data from re-rendering. How do l do that?

```
customDropDownList = () =>{
<DropDownList >

</DropDownList>
}

return(
<List>
//some data
</List>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setState({visbile:true})}>
<Text>Open DropDown list</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
{this.visible == true ? this.customDropDownList : null}
)
```

Comment: Hello! Could you provide the code where you want to achieve this, and what you already tried ? It would help narrow the problem to deal with. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it by a simple condition like this.

```js
function app() {
  const [isOpened, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <DropDown onOpen={() => setOpen(true)} />
      {!isOpened && <List />}
    </>
  );
}
```